# Scheduling UILocalNotification causing lagging and delay of user interface

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I have a function `scheduleFutureLocalNotifications()` in Swift code that creates 64 `UILocalNotification` that fire in the future.

Originally the function was called at `viewDidLoad()`, but this caused delays when starting the app.

Next, the function was called during the active application, but this caused unpredictable pauses or lagging of the user interface.

Finally, the function was moved to trigger when the app transitions to the background after receiving a `UIApplicationDidEnterBackground` notification, but this causes iOS to briefly lag as the local notifications are prepared in the background. This appears more evident on older devices.

**Question:**

> 1 - How can I reduce lag and improve user interface responsiveness
>   creating local notifications?
>
> 2 - What better techniques can be employed to schedule the 64
>   notifications?
>
> 3 - What other better times could the function `scheduleFutureLocalNotifications()` be called?

**Code:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scheduleFutureLocalNotifications()
    }

    func scheduleFutureLocalNotifications() {

        // Remove all previous local notifications
        let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        application.cancelAllLocalNotifications()

        // Set new local notifications to fire over the coming 64 days
        for nextLocalNotification in 1...64 {

            // Add calendar day
            let addDayComponent = NSDateComponents()
            addDayComponent.day = nextLocalNotification
            let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
            let nextDate = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(addDayComponent, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])

            // Set day components for next fire date
            let nextLocalNotificationDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
            let components = nextLocalNotificationDate.components([.Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: nextDate!)
            let year = components.year
            let month = components.month
            let day = components.day

            // Set notification fire date
            let componentsFireDate = NSDateComponents()
            componentsFireDate.year = year
            componentsFireDate.month = month
            componentsFireDate.day = day
            componentsFireDate.hour = 0
            componentsFireDate.minute = 0
            componentsFireDate.second = 5
            let fireDateLocalNotification = calendar.dateFromComponents(componentsFireDate)!

            // Schedule local notification
            let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
            localNotification.fireDate = fireDateLocalNotification
            localNotification.alertBody = ""
            localNotification.alertAction = ""
            localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
            localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit(rawValue: 0)
            localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = nextLocalNotification

            application.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dispatch the code onto a background thread by wrapping the call to `scheduleFutureLocalNotifications` in a `dispatch_async`

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 could you explain further please? Are you suggesting to do the following? dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {() -> Void in self.scheduleFutureLocalNotifications() })

Comment: And can you explain a bit more about what exactly that does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dispatch the function, asynchronously, onto another queue.  This will ensure that the main queue isn't blocked performing the scheduling and will prevent the UI from becoming unresponsive:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIO‌​RITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
        scheduleFutureLocalNotifications()
    } 
}
```

Comment: this sounds promising, I'll give it a go. Thank you.

Comment: Just one other question, are there any pitfalls using the dispatch I should be aware of? Thanks.

Comment: The main thing you have to be careful of is making sure any UI updates are dispatched on the main queue. That isn't an issue in this code, but if you were updating a text field, for example, you would need to dispatch that back to the main queue